# how to output the data set when using histogram in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In Mma, the Histogram function only generates graphics. I am wondering how I can to get the data set; is there any convenient built-in function for this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 12):

HistogramList was added to Mathematica V8 to expose the binning and height calculations.

```
HistogramList[a]
```

[image]

For V7 you can hack the third argument to get the bins and counts.

```
Histogram[a, Automatic, (Print[{##}]; #2) &]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get in version 7 the output like `HistogramList[a]` by using the `BinCounts` function?

Comment: +1, this is great to know. After `Histogram[a, Automatic, (Print[{##}]; #2) &]` produces the data, if after I manipulate these data, how to plot it out again in histogram form?

Comment: @Qiang Assuming `bins` and `counts` contain the data, you should be able to use something like `Histogram[data, {Union[bins]}, counts&]`. (Untested, as I don't have Mathematica in front of me right now.)

Comment: +1 for HistogramList. One of the many new v8 functions that entered the theater behind my back.

Comment: @Sjoerd Take a look also at `SmoothKernelDistribution`,  `SmoothHistogram` , and `HistogramDistribution`

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a bit of internet searching would help as well. This was my answer (of June 18, 2010) to a similar question in the Mathematica newsgroup comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica:

```
data = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200];
res = Reap[Histogram[data, Automatic, (Sow[{#1, #2}]; #2) &]]
```

[image]

I feel this solution is slightly better than Brett's because it returns the data in a readily usable format.

**EDIT**
To recreate the histogram following any bin or count manipulation you'd proceed as suggested by Brett below. Just have the bin and count ready as follows:

```
bins = Union[ Flatten[res[[2, 1, 1, 1]]]];
counts = res[[2, 1, 1, 2]];
Histogram[data, {bins}, counts &]
```

I'm not sure whether the bins are guaranteed to be in ascending order, so instead of `Union` (which sorts), you might want to use `DeleteDuplicates`.

The `count &` is a trick here. As explained in the help page, a function in the third position is expected to take a bin and count list and returns a height list. In this case it just gobbles up the lists and returns counts.

Comment: I like yours. :) BTW, after getting `{{{-2, -(3/2)}, {-(3/2), -1}, {-1, -(1/2)}, {-(1/2), 0}, {0, 1/2}, {1/
   2, 1}, {1, 3/2}, {3/2, 2}, {2, 5/2}, {5/2, 3}, {3, 7/2}}, {5, 23, 
  36, 37, 43, 27, 18, 9, 1, 0, 1}}`, how to plot it out again? `Histogram[data, {Union[bins]}, counts&]` does not seem to work here in my mma v7. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using V7 and you're upset that by using this trick you can't use a built-in bin height specification ("Count", "Probability", "ProbabilityDensity", etc), you can modify Sjord's answer above to return bins normalized however you want.  For example, if you want bin heights using

```
data = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200];
Histogram[data, Automatic, "Probability"]
```

you could instead use

```
res = Reap[Histogram[data, Automatic, 
           (ret = #2/Length[data]; 
            Sow[{#1, ret}]; ret) &
      ]]
```

The analog for "ProbabilityDensity" is

```
res = Reap[Histogram[data, Automatic, 
           (binWidth = #1[[1]][[2]] - #1[[1]][[1]];
           ret = #2/(Length[data]*binWidth);
           Sow[{#1, ret}]; ret) &
     ]]
```