# FindFit with BinCounts or Histogram in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, histogram, bin

```
daList={62.8347, 88.5806, 74.8825, 61.1739, 66.1062, 42.4912, 62.7023, 
        39.0254, 48.3332, 48.5521, 51.5432, 69.4951, 60.0677, 48.4408, 
        59.273, 30.0093, 94.6293, 43.904, 59.6066, 58.7394, 68.6183, 83.0942, 
        73.1526, 47.7382, 75.6227, 58.7549, 59.2727, 26.7627, 89.493, 
        49.3775, 79.9154, 73.2187, 49.5929, 84.4546, 28.3952, 75.7541, 
        72.5095, 60.5712, 53.2651, 33.5062, 80.4114, 63.7094, 90.2438, 
        55.2248, 44.437, 28.1884, 4.77477, 36.8398, 70.3579, 28.1913, 
        43.9001, 23.8907, 12.7823, 22.3473, 57.6724, 49.0148}
```

The above are a sample of actual data I am dealing with.
I use BinCounts, but this is just to illustrate visually histogram should do it  : I would like to fit the shape of that histogram

```
Histogram@data
```

[image]

I know how to fit datapoints themselves like  :

```
model = 0.2659615202676218` E^(-0.2222222222222222` (x - \[Mu])^2)
FindFit[data, model, \[Mu], x]
```

Which is far from what I wan to do : How can I fit bin-counts/histograms in Mathematica ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have MMA V8 you could use the new `DistributionFitTest`

```
disFitObj = DistributionFitTest[daList, NormalDistribution[a, b],"HypothesisTestData"];

Show[
   SmoothHistogram[daList], 
   Plot[PDF[disFitObj["FittedDistribution"], x], {x, 0, 120}, 
        PlotStyle -> Red
   ], 
   PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image]

```
disFitObj["FittedDistributionParameters"]

(* ==> {a -> 55.8115, b -> 20.3259} *)

disFitObj["FittedDistribution"]

(* ==> NormalDistribution[55.8115, 20.3259] *)
```

It can fit other distributions too.

---

Another useful V8 function is `HistogramList`, which provides you with `Histogram`'s binning data. It takes about all of `Histogram`'s options too.

```
{bins, counts} = HistogramList[daList]

(* ==> {{0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100}, {2, 10, 20, 17, 7}} *)

centers = MovingAverage[bins, 2]

(* ==> {10, 30, 50, 70, 90} *)

model = s E^(-((x - \[Mu])^2/\[Sigma]^2));

pars = FindFit[{centers, counts}\[Transpose], 
                     model, {{\[Mu], 50}, {s, 20}, {\[Sigma], 10}}, x]

(* ==> {\[Mu] -> 56.7075, s -> 20.7153, \[Sigma] -> 31.3521} *)

Show[Histogram[daList],Plot[model /. pars // Evaluate, {x, 0, 120}]]
```

[image]

You could also try `NonlinearModeFit` for fitting. In both cases it is good to come with your own initial parameter values to have the best chances that you end up with a globally optimal fit.

---

In V7 there is no `HistogramList` but you could get the same list using [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Histogram.html):

> The function fh in Histogram[data,bspec,fh] is applied to two
>   arguments: a list of bins {{Subscript[b, 1],Subscript[b,
>   2]},{Subscript[b, 2],Subscript[b, 3]},[Ellipsis]}, and corresponding
>   list of counts {Subscript[c, 1],Subscript[c, 2],[Ellipsis]}. The
>   function should return a list of heights to be used for each of the
>   Subscript[c, i].

This can be used as follows ([from my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239205/how-to-output-the-data-set-when-using-histogram-in-mathematica/5244288#5244288)):

```
Reap[Histogram[daList, Automatic, (Sow[{#1, #2}]; #2) &]][[2]]

(* ==> {{{{{0, 20}, {20, 40}, {40, 60}, {60, 80}, {80, 100}}, {2, 
    10, 20, 17, 7}}}} *)
```

---

Of course, you can still use `BinCounts` but the you miss MMA's automatic binning algorithms. You have to provide a binning of your own:

```
counts = BinCounts[daList, {0, Ceiling[Max[daList], 10], 10}]

(* ==>  {1, 1, 6, 4, 11, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2} *)

centers = Table[c + 5, {c, 0, Ceiling[Max[daList] - 10, 10], 10}]

(* ==>  {5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95} *)

pars = FindFit[{centers, counts}\[Transpose],
                model, {{\[Mu], 50}, {s, 20}, {\[Sigma], 10}}, x]

(* ==> \[Mu] -> 56.6575, s -> 10.0184, \[Sigma] -> 32.8779} *)

Show[
   Histogram[daList, {0, Ceiling[Max[daList], 10], 10}], 
   Plot[model /. pars // Evaluate, {x, 0, 120}]
]
```

[image]

As you can see the fit parameters may depend quite a bit on your binning choice. Particularly the parameter I called `s` depends critically on the amount of bins. The more bins, the lower the individual bin counts and the lower the value of `s` will be.